# Automatically closing window after uploading file in Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

I want my code to be able to close the import window automatically after you upload a file in. How can I refine my code to do this instead of using a button to manually close this window?

This is what I have used so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm


root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 
'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

def getCSV ():
    global df1

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df1 = pd.read_csv (import_file_path)
    print (df1)

browseButton_CSV = tk.Button(text=" Import node CSV File  ",
command=getCSV, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_CSV)

def close_window ():
    root.destroy()

button = tk.Button(text = "Click and Quit", command = close_window)
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Move `root.destroy()` inside `getCSV()`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght it gave me an invalid syntax?